# Pagination with React from JSON data issue

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, pagination

I'm stucked into a newbie problem for reactJS(I've started to learn last week). I'm developing a single page application that renders a search result from the Google Book API, and everything looks great, I can fetch the data from the api (actually right now im using AJAX).

None what I've tried in the last 8 hours seens to work to update the state in my [react-paginate](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-paginate) component. **Probably** the problem is in my handlePageClick function, but the documentation of this module is a little bit odd plus my unfamiliarity with react are making things harder.

So here's my **app.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { compose } from 'redux';
import {
  cloneDeep, findIndex, orderBy, keys, values, transforms
} from 'lodash';
import Bookshelf from './bookshelf.js';
import ReactPaginate from 'react-paginate';

import Header from './layout/header.js';
import Footer from './layout/Footer.js';
import Books from './layout/Books.js';
// import {Paginator, paginate } from './helpers';

const app = document.getElementById('app');



export default class Main extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      items:[],
      offset:0
    };

    this.localSubmit = this.localSubmit.bind(this);
    this.onPerPage = this.onPerPage.bind(this);

    this.handlePageClick = this.handlePageClick.bind(this);

  }


  localSubmit(search) {

    this.setState({items: []});
    var component = this;

    $.get("https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=intitle:" + encodeURIComponent(search) + "&printType=books&orderBy=newest&maxResults=39", function (data) {

      component.setState(data);
      Bookshelf();

      $(".front").css("background", "url(../img/no_book_cover.jpg)");

      for (var i = 0; i < component.state.items.length; i++) {
        if (component.state.items[i].volumeInfo.imageLinks != null) {

          $("#book-" + component.state.items[i].id).find(".front").css("background", "url("+ component.state.items[i].volumeInfo.imageLinks.thumbnail +")");
        }
      }


      $(".front").css("background-size", "100% 100%");
      $(".front").css("border", "2px solid #eee");
      $(".front").css("background-size", "100% 100%");


    });
  }

  handlePageClick(component){
    console.log(component);
    let selected = component.selected;
    let offset = Math.ceil(selected * this.props.perPage);
    console.log("the offset is:"+offset)
    this.setState({offset: offset}, () => {
      // this.localsubmit
    });
  }

  onSelect(page) {
    const pages = Math.ceil(
      this.state.items.length / 9
    );

    console.log(pages);

    this.setState({
      pagination: {
        perPage:this.state.pagination,
        page: Math.min(Math.max(page, 1), pages)
      }
    });
  }
  onPerPage(value) {
    this.setState({
      pagination: {
        page:this.state.pagination,
        perPage: parseInt(value, 10)
      }
    });
  }
  render () {
    const pages = Math.ceil(
      this.state.items.length / 9
    );
    console.log("length:"+this.state.items.length);
    console.log(pages);
    var books = [];
    var content;

    books = this.state.items.map(function(book) {
      return <Books key={book.id} item={book.volumeInfo} identifier={book.id} />;
    });

    if (books.length > 0) {
      content = books;
    } else {
      content = <div className="search-icon" ><span className="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></div>
    }

    return (
      <div>
      <Header localSubmit={this.localSubmit}/>
        <div className="main">
                <div id="bookshelf" className="bookshelf">
            {content}
          </div>
          <ReactPaginate previousLabel={"previous"}
               nextLabel={"next"}
               breakLabel={<a href="">...</a>}
               breakClassName={"break-me"}
               pageCount={this.state.pageCount}
               marginPagesDisplayed={2}
               pageRangeDisplayed={5}
               onPageChange={this.handlePageClick}
               containerClassName={"pagination"}
               subContainerClassName={"pages pagination"}
               activeClassName={"active"} />
        </div>
        <Footer />
      </div>
    );

  }

}

ReactDOM.render(<Main  perPage={10}/>, document.getElementById("app"));
```

And this is another relevant component, the **books** class

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';


var Books = React.createClass({

  getInitialState : function () {
    return ({});
  },
  componentDidMount : function () {

    if (this.props.item != null) {
      this.setState(this.props.item);
    }


  },
  render : function () {

    var authors = "";
    console.log(this.props.item);

    if (this.state.authors != null) {
      for (var i = 0; i < this.state.authors.length; i++) {

        if (i > 1) {
          authors = ", " + this.state.authors[i];
        } else {
          authors = this.state.authors[i];
        }
      }
    }

    var descrip = "...";

    if (this.state.description != null) {
      descrip = this.state.description.substring(0, 180) + "...";
    }

    var id = "";

    if (this.props.identifier != null) {
      id = "book-" + this.props.identifier;
    }

    return (

      <figure>
        <div className="book" id={id}></div>
        <div className="buttons"><a href={this.state.previewLink} target="_blank">Preview</a><a href="#">Details</a></div>
        <figcaption><h2>{this.state.title}<span>{authors}</span></h2></figcaption>
        <div className="details">
          <ul>
            <li>{descrip}</li>
            <li>{this.state.publishedDate}</li>
            <li>{this.state.publisher}</li>
            <li>{this.state.pageCount} pages</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </figure>

    );
  }

});

export default Books;
```

I've already tried another modules for paginate in react without success, and this one looks the easier, but there's something missing, could you guys help me?

Error:
When I click in the next page i got this `Cannot read property 'perPage' of undefined` and in `page 1` the whole content are being displayed, the react-paginate filtering actually it's not working.

Edit 2: 
I've uncommented the line of      `this.handlePageClick = this.handlePageClick.bind(this);` inside the constructor but still getting no filter, and now i don't get any errors, this is driving me crazy =(

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe you could actually describe the error / exception thrown, or at least the expected behaviour and the actual one so we can help you :)

Comment: Definitely @CharlieBrown, look again =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Error: When I click in the next page i got this Cannot read property 'perPage' of undefined and in page 1 the whole content are being displayed, the react-paginate filtering actually it's not working.

You need to bind the `handlePageClick` to `this` in the constructor (the line is commented), like you did with `onPerPage` and another method.

**EDIT 2 after your update**
Ok looks better now. However your code is really messy, I can clearly see you going around, changing things and trying. :) Do yourself a favor and remove all that jQuery code all around, specially in the Ajax handler. If you want a different HTML, simply update your components.

To go straight to your question, and after checking the `react-paginate` docs, it **only renders a paginator for you**, but you still have to `render` only the number of items to be shown. In your code you're mapping the full `this.state.items` array and that will render every book every time.

On top of that, I see you're creating new state pieces in your `onPerPage` and `onSelect` methods which you didn't initialize in your `constructor`.

The only state your app needs is:

1. The `items` returned from the API call
2. The current page
3. Optionally: the page size (items per page), which you declare as a constant outside the component and reuse it everywhere you need, with `const PAGE_SIZE = 9`. You may later turn that into a `prop` so your component's default page size is configurable from the outside.

Given the 2 first keys, declare your initial state in your `constructor` like:

```
this.state = {
  items: [],
  currentPage: 1
}
```

Then, and here's the important part, extract your `items` to `<Book />` mapping logic to a function, that takes into account the `PAGE_SIZE` and `currentPage` to select only the relevant items from the array, something like:

```
renderBooks(){
  var startIndex = (this.state.currentPage-1)*PAGE_SIZE
  var endIndex = startIndex + PAGE_SIZE

  return this.state.items.slice(startIndex, endIndex).map(item =>
    <Book {...your_props} />
}
```

Finally, in your render method simply call that `renderBooks()` function everytime you want to render books (i.e., everytime `this.state.items.length > 0`).

On your events handlers for the Paginate component, simply set the appropiate value for `currentPage` and it will do the trick. You don't need to all the Math stuff, as long as there's no **Next 0.25 page** button in your paginator, you'll be working with integers all the time. :)

Hope it helps!

P.S: what's that `Bookshelf()` call in your AJAX handler? You should only `setState({ items })` there!! And take into account the new state in your `render` methods in all your components.

Comment: The pagination now don't throw me any error, but still don't filter the pages. =(